# mod_proxy: sticky session does not work

Tags: apache, session, load-balancing, jboss7.x, mod-proxy

I have two JBoss AS 7 servers and I'm doing load balancing using `mod_proxy`. Almost everything works fine besides sticky sessions. I have session id in a cookie not in the URL as `JSESSIONID`.

Here is my apache configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off
   ProxyPassReverse / balancer://tutcluster/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://server1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://server2:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off

   <Location / >
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from All
   </Location>

   <Proxy balancer://mycluster/>
      BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=jbossWeb1 retry=60
      BalancerMember http://server2:8080 route=jbossWeb2 retry=60
   </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've found it. There were two problems Firstly I forgot to set `jvmRoute` property in the JBoss configuration. So I set:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="jvmRoute" value="nodeX"/>
</system-properties>
```

and changed workers configuration to:

```
BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=nodeX retry=60
```

The second problem was `nofailover=Off`. It probably caused that some parts of the static content was loaded from one server and some parts of it -- from another one.